Array modifier separates objects
I modeled a Domino dice on my own as a Beginner I wanted to learn and understand.
After my design was completed I applied Ctrl + J and even Ctrl + P Keep Transforms, but the problem was after applying the Array modifier and following curve when I went into Edit Mode to separate the dice to animate, and when I applied the physics with all the settings and hit to play dice dots and dices separate.


Looks like the domino's and the dots are different objects, try selecting the domino tile parts and then the dots, then press Ctrl+J again to join them together.

I did but when I seperate the dice the above image problem appears

It's very difficult to know exactly what you might have done with the limited information you have given. Can I suggest you share your .blend file so we can take a look to help you learn what is causing this. Please follow the directions on this page https://blend-exchange.com/

So nice of you ok I will share the file



Hi muji. Your file does not seem have any animation in it, and I can't replicate your problem. I did however notice that all the objects have been scaled, physics and modifiers can behave strangely when the scale is not 1,1,1. Try applying scale to all the objects ad try again.

Thank you Psyonic.  I will do as you tell me. I will update you if it works. Thank you again
